# Hibernate - Prod vs Dev

Tags: java, database, hibernate, development-environment, production-environment

in my application i am using a command line jvm argument to differentiate whether I am running in production or development. Based on this i proceed to use the relevant configuration / properties files for accessing different databases etc.

With hibernate we have the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file with the property

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">url</property>
```

How can we differentiate two different url's for this to avoid connecting to production in dev and visa versa.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Spring in your project?

Comment: no i am not using spring

Comment: If you have appserver use datasources

Comment: yes i am using maven

Comment: Use maven profiles for what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone already mentioned, the RIGHT way to go is to define the datasources inside the application server and expose them through JNDI names.

If going the right way is not an option and you're using Maven, you could get a workaround with maven resource filtering.

Take a look at the spec: [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

Comment: i used resource filtering

Answer (score 0):

I would also advice to use datasource(JNDI) or Make two difference MySQL port number to differentiate Prod/Dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way for this an example for you;

add files name in WEB-INF which name is classes.

WEB-INF-classes-configDevelopment

```
 - -config.properties                        
 - -log4j.xml
 - -theme-html5.properties
```

WEB-INF-classes-configProduction

```
 - config.properties
 - log4j.xml
 - theme-html5.properties
```

config.properties for test

```
connection.jndiName=jdbc/test
user.loginURI=user/login
```

log4j.xml for test

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <!-- Appenders -->

    <!-- Console Appender -->
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%t %-5p: %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender> 

    <!-- Application Loggers -->

    <!-- 3rdparty Loggers -->

    <logger name="SPGW">
        <level value="debug" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.apache">
        <level value="error" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="error" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate">
        <level value="error" />
    </logger>

    <!-- Root Logger -->
    <root>
        <priority value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

root-context.xml

```
 <!-- APP CONFIGURER -->
        <bean id="appConfigurer" 
            class="YOURPROJECT.PropertyPlaceholderExposer">
            <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
            <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />   
            <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />     
            <property name="locations">
                <list>
                    <value>classpath:configDevelopment/config.properties</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <!-- LOG4J -->
        <bean id="log4jInitializer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
            <property name="staticMethod">
                <value>org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer.initLogging</value>
            </property>
            <property name="arguments">
                <list>
                    <value>classpath:configDevelopment/log4j.xml</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>

<!-- DATA SOURCE -->
    <bean id="_dataSourceProxy"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
       <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
       <property name="jndiName" value="${connection.jndiName}"></property>
       <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"></property>
       <property name="cache" value="false"></property>
       <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"></property>
    </bean>
```

PropertyPlaceholderExposer.java

```
package YOURPROJECT;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.util.StringValueResolver;

public class PropertyPlaceholderExposer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer implements Map<String, String> {

    Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();

    @Override
    protected void processProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory, Properties props)
            throws BeansException {

        this.props.clear();
        for (Entry<Object, Object> e: props.entrySet())
            this.props.put(e.getKey().toString(), e.getValue().toString());

        super.processProperties(beanFactory, props);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doProcessProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactoryToProcess,
            StringValueResolver valueResolver) {

        super.doProcessProperties(beanFactoryToProcess, valueResolver);

        for(Entry<String, String> e: props.entrySet())
            e.setValue(valueResolver.resolveStringValue(e.getValue()));
    }

    // Implement map interface to access stored properties
    @Override public Set<String> keySet() { return props.keySet(); }
    @Override public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<String, String>> entrySet() { return props.entrySet(); }
    @Override public Collection<String> values() { return props.values(); }
    @Override public int size() { return props.size(); }
    @Override public boolean isEmpty() { return props.isEmpty(); }
    @Override public boolean containsValue(Object value) { return props.containsValue(value); }
    @Override public boolean containsKey(Object key) { return props.containsKey(key); }
    @Override public String get(Object key) { return props.get(key); }
    @Override public void clear() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    @Override public String put(String key, String value) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    @Override public String remove(Object key) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    @Override public void putAll(Map<? extends String, ? extends String> t) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }

}
```

Comment: ummm... he / she is not using Spring :)

Comment: I thought he/she is using spring :S